# Alterting cute file browser to be comaptible with any jquery version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been experimenting with cute file browser (perfect for my project).

[Cute File Browser](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php/)

But came accross a incomaptibiliy issue. Im not getting any errors in console, but im also not getting any elements being rendered. I have switched libraries about and I think this plugin only works with jquery version 1.11.0, the version my project is using is 1.11.3.

**How should I attempt to fix/update this small script?**

**CUTE SCRIPT:**

```
$(function(){

 var filemanager = $('.filemanager'),
    breadcrumbs = $('.breadcrumbs'),
    fileList = filemanager.find('.data');

// Start by fetching the file data from scan.php with an AJAX request

$.get('scan.php', function(data) {

    var response = [data],
        currentPath = '',
        breadcrumbsUrls = [];

    var folders = [],
        files = [];

    // This event listener monitors changes on the URL. We use it to
    // capture back/forward navigation in the browser.

    $(window).on('hashchange', function(){

        goto(window.location.hash);

        // We are triggering the event. This will execute 
        // this function on page load, so that we show the correct folder:

    }).trigger('hashchange');


    // Hiding and showing the search box

    filemanager.find('.search').click(function(){

        var search = $(this);

        search.find('span').hide();
        search.find('input[type=search]').show().focus();

    });


    // Listening for keyboard input on the search field.
    // We are using the "input" event which detects cut and paste
    // in addition to keyboard input.

    filemanager.find('input').on('input', function(e){

        folders = [];
        files = [];

        var value = this.value.trim();

        if(value.length) {

            filemanager.addClass('searching');

            // Update the hash on every key stroke
            window.location.hash = 'search=' + value.trim();

        }

        else {

            filemanager.removeClass('searching');
            window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(currentPath);

        }

    }).on('keyup', function(e){

        // Clicking 'ESC' button triggers focusout and cancels the search

        var search = $(this);

        if(e.keyCode == 27) {

            search.trigger('focusout');

        }

    }).focusout(function(e){

        // Cancel the search

        var search = $(this);

        if(!search.val().trim().length) {

            window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(currentPath);
            search.hide();
            search.parent().find('span').show();

        }

    });


    // Clicking on folders

    fileList.on('click', 'li.folders', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var nextDir = $(this).find('a.folders').attr('href');

        if(filemanager.hasClass('searching')) {

            // Building the breadcrumbs

            breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(nextDir);

            filemanager.removeClass('searching');
            filemanager.find('input[type=search]').val('').hide();
            filemanager.find('span').show();
        }
        else {
            breadcrumbsUrls.push(nextDir);
        }

        window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(nextDir);
        currentPath = nextDir;
    });


    // Clicking on breadcrumbs

    breadcrumbs.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var index = breadcrumbs.find('a').index($(this)),
            nextDir = breadcrumbsUrls[index];

        breadcrumbsUrls.length = Number(index);

        window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(nextDir);

    });


    // Navigates to the given hash (path)

    function goto(hash) {

        hash = decodeURIComponent(hash).slice(1).split('=');

        if (hash.length) {
            var rendered = '';

            // if hash has search in it

            if (hash[0] === 'search') {

                filemanager.addClass('searching');
                rendered = searchData(response, hash[1].toLowerCase());

                if (rendered.length) {
                    currentPath = hash[0];
                    render(rendered);
                }
                else {
                    render(rendered);
                }

            }

            // if hash is some path

            else if (hash[0].trim().length) {

                rendered = searchByPath(hash[0]);

                if (rendered.length) {

                    currentPath = hash[0];
                    breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(hash[0]);
                    render(rendered);

                }
                else {
                    currentPath = hash[0];
                    breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(hash[0]);
                    render(rendered);
                }

            }

            // if there is no hash

            else {
                currentPath = data.path;
                breadcrumbsUrls.push(data.path);
                render(searchByPath(data.path));
            }
        }
    }

    // Splits a file path and turns it into clickable breadcrumbs

    function generateBreadcrumbs(nextDir){
        var path = nextDir.split('/').slice(0);
        for(var i=1;i<path.length;i++){
            path[i] = path[i-1]+ '/' +path[i];
        }
        return path;
    }


    // Locates a file by path

    function searchByPath(dir) {
        var path = dir.split('/'),
            demo = response,
            flag = 0;

        for(var i=0;i<path.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<demo.length;j++){
                if(demo[j].name === path[i]){
                    flag = 1;
                    demo = demo[j].items;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        demo = flag ? demo : [];
        return demo;
    }


    // Recursively search through the file tree

    function searchData(data, searchTerms) {

        data.forEach(function(d){
            if(d.type === 'folder') {

                searchData(d.items,searchTerms);

                if(d.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerms)) {
                    folders.push(d);
                }
            }
            else if(d.type === 'file') {
                if(d.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerms)) {
                    files.push(d);
                }
            }
        });
        return {folders: folders, files: files};
    }


    // Render the HTML for the file manager

    function render(data) {

        var scannedFolders = [],
            scannedFiles = [];

        if(Array.isArray(data)) {

            data.forEach(function (d) {

                if (d.type === 'folder') {
                    scannedFolders.push(d);
                }
                else if (d.type === 'file') {
                    scannedFiles.push(d);
                }

            });

        }
        else if(typeof data === 'object') {

            scannedFolders = data.folders;
            scannedFiles = data.files;

        }


        // Empty the old result and make the new one

        fileList.empty().hide();

        if(!scannedFolders.length && !scannedFiles.length) {
            filemanager.find('.nothingfound').show();
        }
        else {
            filemanager.find('.nothingfound').hide();
        }

        if(scannedFolders.length) {

            scannedFolders.forEach(function(f) {

                var itemsLength = f.items.length,
                    name = escapeHTML(f.name),
                    icon = '<span class="icon folder"></span>';

                if(itemsLength) {
                    icon = '<span class="icon folder full"></span>';
                }

                if(itemsLength == 1) {
                    itemsLength += ' item';
                }
                else if(itemsLength > 1) {
                    itemsLength += ' items';
                }
                else {
                    itemsLength = 'Empty';
                }

                var folder = $('<li class="folders"><a href="'+ f.path +'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="folders">'+icon+'<span class="name">' + name + '</span> <span class="details">' + itemsLength + '</span></a></li>');
                folder.appendTo(fileList);
            });

        }

        if(scannedFiles.length) {

            scannedFiles.forEach(function(f) {

                var fileSize = bytesToSize(f.size),
                    name = escapeHTML(f.name),
                    fileType = name.split('.'),
                    icon = '<span class="icon file"></span>';

                fileType = fileType[fileType.length-1];

                icon = '<span class="icon file f-'+fileType+'">.'+fileType+'</span>';

                var file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ f.path+'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li>');
                file.appendTo(fileList);
            });

        }


        // Generate the breadcrumbs

        var url = '';

        if(filemanager.hasClass('searching')){

            url = '<span>Search results: </span>';
            fileList.removeClass('animated');

        }
        else {

            fileList.addClass('animated');

            breadcrumbsUrls.forEach(function (u, i) {

                var name = u.split('/');

                if (i !== breadcrumbsUrls.length - 1) {
                    url += '<a href="'+u+'"><span class="folderName">' + name[name.length-1] + '</span></a> <span class="arrow">→</span> ';
                }
                else {
                    url += '<span class="folderName">' + name[name.length-1] + '</span>';
                }

            });

        }

        breadcrumbs.text('').append(url);


        // Show the generated elements

        fileList.animate({'display':'inline-block'});

    }


    // This function escapes special html characters in names

    function escapeHTML(text) {
        return text.replace(/\&/g,'&amp;').replace(/\</g,'&lt;').replace(/\>/g,'&gt;');
    }


    // Convert file sizes from bytes to human readable units

    function bytesToSize(bytes) {
        var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
        if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
        var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
        return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
      }

   });
});
```

Comment: If you know the highest version that works in the browser is 1.10.0 then try to do the changes in your project to run with that version. It shouldn't be that hard, fortunately you don't need to downgrade from 2.0

Comment: @Gavreil - Thanks for suggestion, guess theres not much impact going back... kinda dont want to be resricted by version, could effect updates for other plugins.

Comment: Realy.. is it such a bad question it needs down-vote?

Comment: Yes, there's no useful information in the question, even the "small script" is only mentioned and not included. Also as it turned out from your own answer the problem was not the version of jquery, so even the title is misleading

Comment: @Gravreil - After finding the solution and noticing the offical source has no example code I have altered the question to be more consise to the issue at hand. Although the problem is not specifically the jquery version, it is still a vital part of the issue due to the need to upgrade or use alternative versions.

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked certain jquery methods around in the render function using the 1.11.3 version and it appears `animate()` was causing the issues.

*Change Script.js line 375:*

- From `fileList.animate({'display':'inline-block'});`
- To `fileList.css('display','inline-block');`.

**EDIT:**

I noticed a slightly more improved method of revealing the hidden filelist without using inline styles and adding it to a more appoporate section of the script. Simply use `filelist.show()` in the following section of the render function.

*change Script.js line 286-291:*

```
   if(!scannedFolders.length && !scannedFiles.length) {
        filemanager.find('.nothingfound').show();
        fileList.hide();
    }
    else {
        filemanager.find('.nothingfound').hide();
        fileList.show();
    }
```

Hiding the filelist using `filelist.hide()` also helped me with a style bug relating to the `.nothing-found` error message being pushed down to the bottom of the page when needing to use a fixed height on the filelist.

Now im not depenedant on what version of jquery im using. Hope this helps others using this nice little script.

Comment: No I don't think it's very useful, cause as the question, the answer lacks information so IMHO it's useless for anybody else. Maybe if you fix the question then users with the exact same problem might be attracted here, if there's any.

Comment: @Gavreil - Thanks for the critisim, but your comment/downvote is related to the question not the answer, which has solved the issue not matter how its presented.